# Many small tables include in a bigger table

Tags: python, pyqt5, widget

I have to create one or more displayboards that will contain smaller tables as you can see from the photos.

Image with 10 names - unusable:
[image: Image with 10 names - unusable]

Image with 6 names - 5 are missing:
[image: Image with 6 names - 5 are missing]

The problem is that I can't get either a display board extended in length with a scrollbar or two or more displayboards (it depends on how many names are to be entered). I have tried various systems but in the case of "long displayboard" even varying the values ​in `window.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect (0, 0, 980, 620))` I can't get the scrollbar, in the case of more displayboards I just can't manage get nothing.

This is the starting piece of code that I used to get the code to work

```
from functions import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SpecialStyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._values = dict()

    def add_text(self, text, row):
        self._values[row] = text

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        row = index.row()
        if row in self._values:
            option.text = self._values[row]
            option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter


class MakeStrip(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, anno, mese):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(anno, mese)

    def initUI(self, anno, mese):

        self.title = "MAMbo - Strips di '%s' '%s' " % (mese, anno)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(50, 100, 250, 800)
        self.callTable(anno, mese)
        self.Close_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Close_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1000, 570, 70, 20))
        self.Close_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : yellow")
        self.Close_btn.setObjectName("Strip_Add_btn")
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.Close_btn.setText(_translate("Library_main", "Close"))
        self.Close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.Close_btn)
    def callTable(self, anno, mese):
        anno = "2021"
        self.alphamese = "January"
        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)

        self.special_delegate = SpecialStyledItemDelegate()
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.special_delegate)

        self.special_delegate.add_text("JOE DOE", 0)
        self.special_delegate.add_text("January", 1)

        h_header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        h_header.hide()
        for i in range(h_header.count()):
            h_header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        v_header = self.tableWidget.verticalHeader()
        v_header.hide()
        v_header.setDefaultSectionSize(13)

        self.tableWidget.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.tableWidget.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 3)

        for zz in range(1, 10):
            dow = "do{}".format(zz)
            value = "AAAAAAAA{}".format(zz)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(zz + 1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(zz)))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(zz + 1, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(dow))
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(value)
            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(zz + 1, 2, item)

    def close (self):
       Functions.error_handler(message="message")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    anno = "2021"
    mese = "January"
    ex = MakeStrip(anno, mese)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below, the job code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
from functions import *
from index import *


class SpecialStyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._values = dict()

    def add_text(self, text, row):
        self._values[row] = text

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        row = index.row()
        if row in self._values:
            option.text = self._values[row]
            option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter



class Make_Strip():

    def MakeStrip(self,  window: QWindow, anno, mese, cursor):


        global table
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.alphamese =  Functions.convert_number_month[mese]

        cursor = Functions.openDB(self)
        query = "SELECT * FROM `alldata` WHERE anno = '%s' AND mese = '%s' " % (anno, mese)
        self.cursor.execute(query)
        search = self.cursor.fetchall()
        #numrows = self.cursor.rowcount()
        cnt= 0
        x_ax = 10
        for row in search:
            if cnt == 6: break # This is to have something useful (picture 2)
            self.vol_name = row['nome']
            self.c_query = "SELECT grp FROM volontari WHERE cognome = '%s'" % (self.vol_name)
            self.cursor.execute(self.c_query)
            self.grp = self.cursor.fetchall()
            for val in self.grp:
                self.group = val['grp']
                if self.group == 'C':
                    table = QTableWidget()
                    table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x_ax, 5, 150, 597))
                    table.setObjectName("StripTable")
                    table.setRowCount(33)
                    table.setColumnCount(3)

                    self.special_delegate = SpecialStyledItemDelegate()
                    table.setItemDelegate(self.special_delegate)

                    h_header = table.horizontalHeader()
                    h_header.hide()
                    for i in range(h_header.count()):
                        h_header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
                    v_header = table.verticalHeader()
                    v_header.hide()
                    v_header.setDefaultSectionSize(18)

                    table.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)
                    table.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 3)

                    zz = 1
                    self.m_query =  "SELECT * FROM `alldata` WHERE anno = '%s' AND mese = '%s' AND nome = '%s'" %(anno, mese, self.vol_name)
                    self.cursor.execute(self.m_query)
                    result = self.cursor.fetchall()
                    self.special_delegate.add_text(self.vol_name, 0)
                    self.special_delegate.add_text(self.alphamese, 1)
                    daysinmonth = calendar.monthrange(int(anno), int(mese))[1]
                while zz <= daysinmonth:
                        for inrow in result:
                            day = 'd' + str(zz)
                            self.value = inrow[day]
                            a_date = datetime.date(int(anno), int(mese), zz)
                            self.dow = a_date.strftime("%a")
                            self.dow = Functions.convert_en_it[self.dow]
                            if (self.dow == 'Sun' or self.dow == 'Sat') and (self.value == 'P' or self.value == 'D' or self.value == 'F' or  self.value == 'B'):
                                self.value = Functions.eva_mp1[self.value]
                            else: self.value = Functions.eva_mp[self.value]
                            table.setItem(zz+1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(zz)))
                            table.setItem(zz+1, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.dow))
                            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.value)
                            item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                            table.setItem(zz+1, 2, item)
                            zz += 1
                        #table.show()
            cnt = cnt + 1
            x_ax = x_ax + 150
            layout.addWidget(table)
            pippo = 0

        window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 980, 620))
        window.setLayout(layout)
        window.show()
```

Comment: Can't you just set a minimum width for every table?

Comment: No, because there are tables see "FRANCESCHINI" that must contain longer information while others, see "FIOCCHI" have less. And in any case I would never be able to get 10 or more tables into that area. The tables must be readable because after a screenshot and a crop with gimp I have to send them to each name. I was thinking of a pop up as big as the monitor but nothing works at the moment. If you have any ideas in this regard, I would appreciate it very much

Comment: you mentioned a scroll bar, so I thought you were using a QScrollArea. If your are not, you should: scroll bars don't appear out of nothing. If you need more detailed answers, provide a [mre].

Comment: I did not know QScrollArea. I try to study it a little bit and I'll let you know. Thank you. Stay tuned :)

Comment: there are more than 200 classes in the QtWidgets module alone (and similar amounts in QtGui and QtCore), of which at least a third are actual widgets. I strongly suggest you to carefully and patiently [browse them](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) so that you'll better know some of the UI features of Qt. Note that the most important of them are available in Qt Designer from the widget box panel, so you could experiment with them, learn how they work and what their capabilities are.